# How to match obstacles with music in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, music

How to match obstacles with music in Unity?

I want to make a game like Beat Saber where game events are synchronized with the beats of a song.

Comment: what are you looking for exacly? how a music can be matched with an obstacle?

Comment: Did you play beat saber i wanna make a game like that.

Comment: you can have many approaches. you can do some audio analysis to detect simply volum equlizer or make a tool that designer can manually define right places form drum beats. as a game need to be controlled, automated system cant be trusted you should make a system that boxes arrive at player(camera at right moment of song) it cant be something very hard

Comment: "Is there any assets or plugin?" is a question [you can answer for yourself by doing a simple search](https://assetstore.unity.com/?q=music%20matching&orderBy=0), so it's not a topic we handle on this site. How have you tried to use [the material you've found from searching](https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-rogers-ca-revc&ei=O1LeXauQI5Cf_Qav7qbACg&q=beat+matching+unity) so far, [including existing Q&A on this site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/146605/39518)? What step do you need help with?

Comment: DMGregory to prepare an algorithm of it

Comment: An algorithm that does what, exactly? Are you asking about [detecting beats in a user-provided audio track](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=beat+detection+algorithm&t=hk&ia=web)? Beat Sabre does not do this. Each music-synchronized game event in its songs - like the timings of the cubes - was authored by the game development team. If that's not what you mean, then what are the inputs and outputs of the algorithm you have in mind?